# How to start a cron using Quartz at start of hour each hour ?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

From the documentation below, I assume "0 0 * * * *" is the right answer.
I wanted to double verify:

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html

Comment: Use a tool like http://cron.schlitt.info to check your cron expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following expression runs every one hour at the start of each hour.

`0 0 0/1 1/1 * ? *`

Answer (score 1):

What you have would only start it on the zero hour.  You need to specify every hour by using a slash.

```
0 0 0/1 * * ?
```